# In-App purchase restore button restores non purchased In-Apps

Tags: arrays, objective-c, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am very lost when it comes to in app purchases. I found a very solid post on stack overflow that has been helpful. [Stack Post][1] I am still having issues after this though. If I have an in app purchase thats never been bought before and I tap the restore button it will unlock it anyway. Any help would be amazing thanks.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    @IBOutlet weak var nonConsumableLabel: UILabel!

    let id_sold = "id_sold"
    var productID = ""
    var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest()
    var iapProducts = [SKProduct]()
    var nonConsumablePurchaseMade = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "nonConsumablePurchaseMade")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Check your In-App Purchases
    print("NON CONSUMABLE PURCHASE MADE: \(nonConsumablePurchaseMade)")

    if nonConsumablePurchaseMade { nonConsumableLabel.text = "Premium version PURCHASED!"
    } else { nonConsumableLabel.text = "Premium version LOCKED!"}

    // Fetch IAP Products available
    fetchAvailableProducts()
}


@IBAction func nonConsumableBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    purchaseMyProduct(product: iapProducts[0])
}

@IBAction func printer(_ sender: Any) {
    print(iapProducts)
}


// MARK: - RESTORE NON-CONSUMABLE PURCHASE BUTTON
@IBAction func restorePurchaseButt(_ sender: Any) {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    nonConsumablePurchaseMade = true
    UserDefaults.standard.set(nonConsumablePurchaseMade, forKey: "nonConsumablePurchaseMade")


    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "IAP Tutorial", message: "You've successfully restored your purchase!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodID {
            case "id_sold":
                // implement the given in-app purchase as if it were bought
                print("Second IAP restored")
            default:
                print("iap not found")
            }
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - FETCH AVAILABLE IAP PRODUCTS
func fetchAvailableProducts()  {

    // Put here your IAP Products ID's
    let productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects:
        id_sold
    )

    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
    productsRequest.delegate = self
    productsRequest.start()
}


// MARK: - REQUEST IAP PRODUCTS
func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {
    if (response.products.count > 0) {
        iapProducts = response.products

        // Get its price from iTunes Connect
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

        // 2nd IAP Product (Non-Consumable) ------------------------------
        let secondProd = response.products[0] as SKProduct

        // Get its price from iTunes Connect
        numberFormatter.locale = secondProd.priceLocale
    }
}




// MARK: - MAKE PURCHASE OF A PRODUCT
func canMakePurchases() -> Bool {  return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()  }
func purchaseMyProduct(product: SKProduct) {
    if self.canMakePurchases() {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

        print("PRODUCT TO PURCHASE: \(product.productIdentifier)")
        productID = product.productIdentifier


    // IAP Purchases dsabled on the Device
    } else {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "IAP Tutorial", message: "You've successfully restored your purchase!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}



// MARK:- IAP PAYMENT QUEUE
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
                switch trans.transactionState {

                case .purchased:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

                    if productID == id_sold {

                        // Save your purchase locally (needed only for Non-Consumable IAP)
                        nonConsumablePurchaseMade = true
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(nonConsumablePurchaseMade, forKey: "nonConsumablePurchaseMade")

                        nonConsumableLabel.text = "Premium version PURCHASED!"



                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "IAP Tutorial", message: "You've successfully unlocked the Premium version!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true)
                    }

                    break

                case .failed:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .restored:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    nonConsumablePurchaseMade = true
    UserDefaults.standard.set(nonConsumablePurchaseMade, forKey: "nonConsumablePurchaseMade")
}
```

But that method is called even if nothing was restored. All it means is that the restoration interaction is *over*, not that it *succeeded*. But you are going ahead and acting as if it succeeded, and awarding your user the magic user defaults key.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. How do I go about changing that to verify if it was successful?

Comment: Well, all the action takes place in `paymentQueue(_ queue:updatedTransactions:)`. But you didn't show that method. And the code you did show makes no sense at all, since you have _two_ implementations of `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`. So I've no idea what else you're up to. I've told you the source of the issue, that's all I can do based on what you've revealed.

Comment: Okay, I updated my code to show all of my code currently used for my in Apps.

Comment: Well you've still got the two implementations of `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`. I would suggest deleting them; you don't need them for anything. Basically in your `updatedTransactions` method you want to change `case .purchased` to `case .purchased, .restored`. There is so much else wrong with your `updatedTransactions` that I can't really deal with it here; it would take a whole separate question. But why don't you do a little searching? How to write a correct `updatedTransactions` has been explained many, many times already.

Comment: Okay thank you for the insight. I have been working on this for weeks and am pretty much stumped. I have over hauled it several times.

Comment: Well, as I say, there's so much boilerplate sample code out there, there isn't much need to spend any time thinking. :)